# How do I encrypt a build step?

Tags: encryption, travis-ci

I need a secret token to be part of a command executed by Travis CI, but am in a public repository.  I found that I can [encrypt parts of `.travis.yml`](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/encryption-keys/) to keep secrets safe.  However, encrypting the command like in the following example fails saying `Y95MgqDf...Bc=}: No such file or directory`

```yaml
after_deploy:
- secure: "Y95MgqDf...Bc="
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't encrypt the step. That does not appear to be supported by Travis.

Instead, encrypt only secret part:

```bash
$ travis encrypt TOKEN=verysecret
secure: "CnLZ...lI="
```

Put the secret in an environment variable:

```yaml
env:
  global:
    secure: CnLZ...lI=
```

Then dereference the environment variable when you need your secret.

```yaml
after_deploy:
- mycommand $TOKEN
```